# crossfilter filterAll missing value

Tags: crossfilter

I am having a strange issue. After clearing all filters on one dimension, one of the entries is missing from that dimension but it is still in the crossfilter. See example code here:

```js
types.filter('visa');
payments.remove();
types.filterAll();
```

For more details look at that fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RFontana/6YWSd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this has been fixed as of version 1.3.7
See http://jsfiddle.net/RFontana/6YWSd/7/

```
types.filter('visa');
payments.remove();
types.filterAll();
```